# How do you prevent Xcode from auto selecting the Team Profile?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, provisioning

I'm having a problem with Xcode and GIT. I have my provisioning profile set to "auto select", on my computer the profile selected is correct (Com.Company.App), but when my partner updates their code rather then selecting their correct version of the profile, it selects the Team Profile (Com.Company.*).

How do I tell Xcode that I want it to explicitly use the com.company.app profile and not the team profile ?

Thanks for the assistance.

EDIT: Updating this question with some additional information. The issue is coming from Xcode auto selecting the 1st Team profile in my list (I have multiple team profiles for various clients) The client that I am working on is number 3 on the list... If I manually select the correct profile everything works properly, until I update from GIT and then it defaults back to the 1st one on the list... Its very frustrating...

Comment: Does your partner have the proper provisioning profile and certificates installed to sign apps with com.company.app? Can your partner select the option to sign with com.company.app in build settings?

Comment: Yes- He can manually select the proper certificate and build the app without any issues at all. And when he checks his code in, xcode selects the proper certificate from my keychain. Its only when the checkin is coming from my computer that there is a problem.

Comment: The auto selector should prefer more specific profiles over a wildcard profile. Check to make sure the bundle identifier for your target matches case with the bundle identifier in the provisioning profile on both computers.

Comment: I think you might be on the right track, I had assumed the BundleID was correct since I was joining this project midway through, and it turns out it may not reflect the correct provisioning profile

Answer (score 0):

To manage accounts and other settings, you can go to xcode preferences > accounts and now you can manage the things.